# Replace String in List of List

Tags: python, list

As I learn Python I'm struggling in writing a loop to replace `string` in a list of list. Please see the following MWE,

```
list=[['a','alpha'],['b','bravo'],['c','charlie'],['d','delta']]

for entry in list:
    name = entry[1]
    
    if name == 'alpha':
        name = name.replace('alpha','zulu')    
    
    if name == 'bravo':
        name = name.replace('bravo','zulu')   
    
    else:
        name = 'xxx'
    
    entry[1] = name

print(list)
```

I recognize that the issue is my loop is simply replacing the value with each iteration and therefore not yielding my desired output:
`[['a', 'zulu'], ['b', 'zulu'], ['c', 'xxx'], ['d', 'xxx']]`. Is there a way of editing my loop so achieve the desired result? Beyond the MWE, I'm working with a fairly large dataset and `else` command is quite useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: There's no need for `replace`. Just write `name = 'zulu'`

Comment: Change the second `if` to `elif`.

Comment: The issue with the original code is that the second if statement is not connected to the first one, so the else block is only related to the second if. This means that if name is 'alpha', it will be replaced with 'zulu', but then immediately replaced with 'xxx' by the else block.

**You can fix this by using elif.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use assignment a la `name = 'whatever'` rather than using `replace`

Likewise, you can combine the check for `alpha` and `bravo` since the replacement value is identical:

```
entries = [['a','alpha'],['b','bravo'],['c','charlie'],['d','delta']]

for entry in entries:
    name = entry[1]
    if name == 'alpha' or name == 'bravo':
        name = 'zulu'
    else:
        name = 'xxx'
    
    entry[1] = name  # update the list item

print(list)
# => [['a', 'zulu'], ['b', 'zulu'], ['c', 'xxx'], ['d', 'xxx']]
```

And as @Barmar mentioned, `list` is a reserved word in Python, so I've renamed your list to `entries`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, I'm learning so much from this community!